# How can I prevent .stop() in certain situations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm designing a simple jquery animation so when you click a tile, it displays its info by hiding all other tiles, and displaying its information. Its basic stuff. My problem exists in the deeper core of jquery where although I am using .stop() to prevent queuing, I don't want to want .stop() to function during the animation when it transitions out the tiles and displays the description.

My code is broken down in 3 parts. 1st is a mouseeneter which changes the opacity to adjust the opacity of each tile, the 2nd one is the mouseleave where it changes either the opacity of all tiles to normal, or adjusts the others if the mouse enters another tile. The last is basically a click function where if you click a tile, it will fade the other 4 out and show the product description. The third part is the part where things get tricky. The .stop() function in the first part is interfering with the animation when you click if your mouse happens to be in the way during the animation. I don't know how to remedy this issue.

```
function bannerFader(currentBanner, otherBanners, expandButton, appendInfo){
var disableHover = false;
    $(currentBanner).mouseenter(function(){
        if (disableHover == false) {
            $(otherBanners).stop(true);
            $(otherBanners).fadeTo(100, .8);
        }
    });
    $(currentBanner).mouseleave(function(){
        if (disableHover == false) {
            $(otherBanners).fadeTo(100, 1);
        };
    });
    $(expandButton).click(function(){
        disableHover = true;
        $(otherBanners).hide(200, function(){
            $(appendInfo).show(300);
        });
    });
}

function autoRunner() {
    bannerFader('.banner-one', '.banner-two, .banner-three, .banner-four, .banner-five', '.banner-one','.append-one')
    bannerFader('.banner-two', '.banner-one, .banner-three, .banner-four, .banner-five', '.banner-two','.append-two')
    bannerFader('.banner-three', '.banner-two, .banner-one, .banner-four, .banner-five', '.banner-three','.append-three')
    bannerFader('.banner-four', '.banner-two, .banner-three, .banner-one, .banner-five', '.banner-four','.append-four')
    bannerFader('.banner-five', '.banner-two, .banner-three, .banner-four, .banner-one', '.banner-five','.append-five')
};
```

Basically, I want everything to work the same way as it does, just without .stop() from interefering with the transition. You can find an example of my problem here:

http://rockforddriveline.com/newrdl/index.html

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you're asking; What I understand is that you want `.stop()` to immediately stop one animation, but not another. You can do this with custom-named queues

Comment: I thought I made it pretty clear as well as the code itself. .stop() is meant to prevent animation queuing when you hover, yet when you click a tile to begin that animation, stop will interfere with it and make it... stop. Look at the website at the bottom of my post and just click any of the 4 tiles on the right and not the one on the far left and just move your mouse to the right when you click and you'll see.

Comment: It would probably be clearer if you posted a jsFiddle with your HTML and CSS. As it is, it's difficult to test possible solutions.

Comment: My code isn't optimized for me to just "stick it in a jsFiddle". I don't know what more you could possibly want than a live website, the javascript, and a description of my problem. I attempted to stick it in jsFiddle and modified it quite a bit to work, but I don't have the time to jostle around my code into a jsFiddle. All I want is to get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I didn't know that different queues existed in JQuery. The default jqueue is "fx" which basically instantiates itself when ever you do standard animations like ".show" or ".hide". Therefore, when you want to be able to do other animations despite other animations (which in my case also includes .stop), you can make your own queue just as user1433150 has pointed out.

Basically, at the end of each animation, you need to "create" a queue:

```
$(otherBanners).fadeTo(200, .8).queue(null,'hoverEvent');
```

Then at the other animations (and .stop), you should make sure they affect or add to 'hoverEvent" so that you can perform seperate animations at the same time without them interfering with each other.

```
$(otherBanners).stop('hoverEvent',true);
```

and:

```
$(otherBanners).fadeTo(200, 1).queue('hoverEvent');
```

Then at the first part of my function, after I "created" a queue, I need to dequeue it to actually call it.

```
$(otherBanners).dequeue();
```

And then after that, you're pretty much good to go. My modified code looks like:
function bannerFader(currentBanner, otherBanners, expandButton, appendInfo){

```
var disableHover = false;

    $(currentBanner).mouseenter(function(){
        if (disableHover == false) {
            $(otherBanners).stop('hoverEvent',true);
            $(otherBanners).fadeTo(200, .8).queue(null,'hoverEvent');
            $(otherBanners).dequeue();
        }
    });
    $(currentBanner).mouseleave(function(){
        if (disableHover == false) {
            $(otherBanners).fadeTo(200, 1).queue('hoverEvent');
        };
    });
    $(expandButton).click(function(){
        disableHover = true;
        $(otherBanners).hide(200, function(){
            $(appendInfo).show(300);
        });
    });
}

function autoRunner() {
    bannerFader('.banner-one', '.banner-two, .banner-three, .banner-four, .banner-five', '.banner-one','.append-one')
    bannerFader('.banner-two', '.banner-one, .banner-three, .banner-four, .banner-five', '.banner-two','.append-two')
    bannerFader('.banner-three', '.banner-two, .banner-one, .banner-four, .banner-five', '.banner-three','.append-three')
    bannerFader('.banner-four', '.banner-two, .banner-three, .banner-one, .banner-five', '.banner-four','.append-four')
    bannerFader('.banner-five', '.banner-two, .banner-three, .banner-four, .banner-one', '.banner-five','.append-five')
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the ability to have separate queues is for. Put the mouseenter/mouseleave triggered animations in a separate queue. Then when you call `stop(true)`, where the first argument of `true` clears the queue, it won't interfere with your click animation. Use `animate` and pass it a queue name in the options argument, then pass the same queue to `stop`, like this `stop('myqueue', true)`

Comment: Not sure where you're headed with this, could you possibly send me a link to a resource to learn to do this, modify my code, or jsFiddle an example? http://api.jquery.com/animate/ Basically is telling me to just set up exactly what I did, but instead of doing seperate functions like .show, .hide, its basically having me do it in CSS.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out. You basically put me on the right track, but didn't exactly have my solution. I'll post my solution.